# Disable Airflow mini-scheduler / fast-follow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I'm running Airflow v2.2.3 on Kubernetes.

I have a dedicated scheduler pod, a dedicated web-server pod and I'm using Kubernetes Executors.

I have ~4,000 DAGs, created dynamically in a for-loop.

I read Astronomer's [post](https://www.astronomer.io/blog/airflow-2-scheduler#single-scheduler-optimization) about "fast-follow" (also called "mini-scheduler") and I wonder if there's an option to disable it via configuration or something.

The thing is, that it comes with a penalty where:

- Dynamic DAGs are being calculated per each task operator, as a new fresh executor is running every time - I never saw reuse of Kubernetes executor (and if it using pod's `patch` verb for that - I guess that the dynamic DAGs would recalculated again anyway).
- The time it takes to recalculate dynamic DAGs lead to a "queued" status for every task - which mean that a lot of time is spent just for recalculating the DAGs over and over again.

1. Is there a configuration (or any other way) to disable the mini-scheduler?
2. Am I using the KubernetesExecutor wrong? should it stay up for more than one task (and thus calculate the dags only at the beginning)
3. I'm running a multi-tenant setup, where each one of my customers (businesses) run it's own DAG - but they all look the same (except input arguments + schedule time). Should I take a different approach? (other than using a dedicated DAG per customer).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1.
This feature introduced in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11589)
To disable the feature set in `airflow.cfg`:

```
[scheduler]
schedule_after_task_execution = False
```

2. Disabling the feature may not be advised as explained in in [config.yml](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f964fd47de5435f5c354c6211d24bd2dfaaffa9e/airflow/config_templates/config.yml#L1886-L1894) description. It may effect performance.
3. Airflow doesn't support multi tenant setup yet. It's currently in discussions under [AIP 1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-1%3A+Improve+Airflow+Security) (with sub AIPs [33](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-43+DAG+Processor+separation?src=contextnavpagetreemode)-[34](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-44+Airflow+Internal+API)).
   That said - I'm not really sure how this question relates to the issue you described before. It's OK to use dedicated DAG per customer. It even makes sense as one customer can backfill / clear previous tasks and you don't want it to cause problems for other customers. This is more a design decision. I don't think there is a right or wrong here - it depends how you organization decide to work.

Comment: thanks @Elad! I'll try to use this config and update if it help - should it prevent the DAGs calculation? About 3 - A colleague of mine suggest to run all customers in a single DAG (with high parallelism) - and I wondered if there's "a best practice here".

Comment: Normally the person who recommend something should provide the reasoning for his recommendation. Wouldn't it be better to just create both scenarios and test it? It should be quite easy to benchmark this and when data is on your side no one can argue :)

Comment: Using the suggested configuration above doesn't prevent from the k8s executor to calculate / load the DAGs. I wonder why - why it's needed if it suppose to run a single task and die

Comment: This setting has nothing to do with Executor (K8s or other). Normally tasks are set to state None and then to Scheduled by the Scheduler. This feature is optimizing the process by checking if downstream task can be set directly to Scheduled state. Which saves some overhead from the scheduler. Executors are entering to the picture when tasks is set to Queued which is not something this feature does.